# Accessing a JSP (using JSTL) variable in INCLUDED javascript file which is included in the same JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Here is a snippet from my JSP file

```
  <c:set var="myVar">
        <spring:eval
            expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('someproperty.in.file')" />
        </c:set>
  <script src="js/myJavascript.js"></script>
```

How do I access the `myVar` in the `myJavaScript.js`?

I have already tried the following things in my JavaScript file, neither of them worked for me

1. `var tempVar = "<%= session.getAttribute(\"myVar\") %>";`
2. `var tempVar = "${myVar}"`;
3. `var tempVar = "<%=myVar%>"`

**Note:** Tested solutions highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSP file, include the definition of the variable before you include your javascript file. If you are referring to a variable set earlier in the JSP file. You can do the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var var = "${var_name}";
</script>
<script src="js/myJavascript.js"></script>
```

In your JavaScript file, you can directly refer to the variable. In this case, you can refer to the variable as "var".

e.g.

```
alert(var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to get the value of `myVar` in javascript.

```
var tempVar="<%=pageContext.getAttribute("myVar")%>" />
```

Simillarly you can get all the values of variables using `Page Context` set on that `JSP` page.

Hope it helps.